# Род существительного во множественном числе числе

Tags: грамматика, морфология

Нужно ли указывать род при морфологическом разборе существительного во множественном числе, **имеющего и единственное число**? Например, при разборе слова *дни*, *кольца*, *машины* я не указываю род, т. к. это — мн. число, а во мн. числе нет рода. Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно ли указывать род при морфологическом разборе существительного во
>   множественном числе, **имеющего и единственное число**?

**Нужно.**

См. [**у Литневской**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm#i2):

> **Существительное разбирается по следующей схеме:**
>
> **1. Начальная форма.**
>
> 2. Морфологические признаки:
>
> **а) постоянные:**
>
> — собственное / нарицательное,
>
> — конкретное / абстрактное / вещественное / собирательное,
>
> **— род,**
>
> — число (для тех существительных, для которых этот признак
>   постоянный),
>
> — одушевленность,
>
> — склонение;
>
> **б) непостоянные:**
>
> **— число (для изменяющихся по числам),**
>
> — падеж.
>
> 3. Синтаксическая роль в предложении.

Comment: СПАСИБО. Значит, при разборе слова, например, дни, нужно привести его в ед число (день) и указать род.